# Make multidimensional array to string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I' am creating a hierarchical menu using MySQL Database. I' am currently stuck at this point where I' am not able to convert the multidimensional array into a string.

**The Outcome**

```
/media/photo-gallery/Title-1
```

**Var Dump of the array**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      string(5) "media"
    }
    [1]=>
    string(13) "photo-gallery"
  }
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Title-1"
}
```

I have tried using Implode function, this is what I get

```
$path = implode("/", $path);
string(19) "Array/photo-gallery"
```

**Get the parent slug from database**

```
function get_path( $page_id ) { 
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = $page_id";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
    $path = array();    
    foreach( $rows as $row ){
        $page_id = $row->page_id;
        $page_parent = $row->page_parent;
        $page_slug = $row->page_slug;

        $path[] = $page_slug;
        $path[] = get_path( $page_parent );
        $path = array_reverse( $path );
        $path = array_filter( $path );
    }
    return $path;
}
```

**Displays the HTML Menu**

```
function display_children( $parent = "0", $level = "0" ){
    global $db;

    echo "<ul>";
    // retrieve all children of $parent 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_parent = $parent";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();        
    foreach( $rows as $row ){
        $page_id = $row->page_id;
        $page_parent = $row->page_parent;
        $page_title = $row->page_title;
        $page_slug = $row->page_slug;

        $path = get_path($page_parent);
        $path = array_unique(array_values($path));          
        var_dump($path);

        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a href=\"\">";
        echo "$page_title | Parent ID: $page_parent";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "</a>";

        // child's children 
        display_children($page_id, $level + 1); 

    }
    echo "</ul>";

}
```

Comment: How is `Title-1` coming under `photo-gallery`? do you mean to merge the `[0]` part recursive and then append `[1]`?

Comment: @bansi Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Firstly Refine your SQL if it is coming from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your input array is in reverse order, the topmost item goes to the end and the last leaf is the first item. Here is a small function which you can try.

```
$path = array(array(array('media'),'photo-gallery'),'Title-1');

var_dump($path);
$path = implode('/',sanitizePath($path));
echo $path;

function sanitizePath($pathArray, $initialPath=array()){
    foreach($pathArray as $a){
        if(is_array($a)){
            $initialPath=sanitizePath($a,$initialPath);
        }else{
            array_push($initialPath,$a);
        }
    }
    return $initialPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array = array(
    0 =>array(
        0 => array("media","photo-gallery"),
    ),
    1 => "Title-1"
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $k1=>$v1){
if(is_array($v1)){
    $new_array = parseArray($new_array, $k1, $v1);
}else{
    $new_array = array_merge($new_array, array($k1=>$v1));
}
}

function parseArray($new_array, $key, $val){
if(is_array($val)){
    foreach($val as $k2=>$v2){
        if(is_array($v2)){
            $new_array = parseArray($new_array, $k2, $v2);
        }else{
            $new_array = array_merge($new_array, array($k2=>$v2));
        }
    }
}else{
    $new_array = array_merge($new_array, array($key=>$val));
}
return $new_array;
}
echo implode('/', $new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
media/photo-gallery/Title-1
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://uk.php.net/spl) you can get the desired output

```
<?php
 $array = array(
    0 =>array(
        0 => array("media","photo-gallery"),
    ),
    1 => "Title-1"
);


$op = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($op as $each) {
  $result .= '/'.$each;
}

echo $result;.
```

**Output:**

> /media/photo-gallery/Title-1